# Multithreaded Realtime audio programming - To block or Not to block

Tags: c++, multithreading, audio

When writing audio software many people on the internet say it is paramount not to use either memory allocation or blocking code, i.e no locks. Due to the fact these are non deterministic so could cause the output buffer to underflow and the audio will glitch.

[Real Time Audio Progrmaming](http://www.rossbencina.com/code/real-time-audio-programming-101-time-waits-for-nothing)

When I write video software, I generally use both, i.e. allocating video frames on the heap and passing between threads using locks and conditional variables (bounded buffers). I love the power this provides as a separate thread can be used for each operation, allowing the software to max out each of the cores, giving the best performance.

With audio I'd like to do something similar, passing frames of maybe 100 samples between threads, however, there are two issues.

1. How do I generate the frames without using memory allocation? I suppose I could use a pool of frames that have been pre-allocated but this seems messy.
2. I'm aware you can use lock free queue and that boost has a nice library to do this. This would be a great way to share between threads, but constantly polling the queue to see if data is available seems like a massive waist of CPU time.

In my experience using mutexes doesn't actually take much time at all, provided that the section where the mutex is locked is short.

What is the best way to achieve passing audio frames between threads, whilst keeping latency to a minimum, not wasting resources and using relatively little non-deterministic behaviour?

Comment: I don't know a lot about audio, but it sounds like a traditional producer/consumer problem, have you looked at counting semaphores?

Comment: Do you even need threads? Audio data is a lot cheaper than video.

Comment: @immibis, well, that depends on what you do in your audio thread. Video usually only do very few operations per pixel while audio synthesis can be very demanding per sample.

Comment: I agree with @immibis. There is going to be next to zero time spent on the thread outputting the audio so you're not going to really "max" out both cores. A single thread is going to be simpler with no real disadvantage.

Comment: I Can promise you that in this software, using a single thread is not an option.

Comment: " There is going to be next to zero time spent on the thread outputting the audio so you're not going to really "max" out both cores."

A single state of the art guitar effect simulation can easily max out a modern i7 core, so no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you did your research! You've already identified the two main problems that could be the root-cause of audio glitches. The question is: How much of this was important 10 years ago and is only folklore and cargo-cult programming these days.

My two cents:

*1. Heap allocations in the rendering loop:*

These can have quite a lot overhead depending on how small your processing chunks are. The main culprit is, that very few run-times have a per-thread heap, so each time you mess with the heap your performance depends on what other threads in your process do. If for example a GUI thread is currently deleting thousands of objects, and you - at the same time - access the heap from the audio rendering thread you may experience a significant delay.

Writing your own memory management with pre-allocated buffers may sound messy, but in the end it's just two functions that you can hide somewhere in a utility source. Since you usually know your allocation sizes in advance there is a lot of opportunity to fine-tune and optimize your memory management. You can store your segments as a simple linked list for example. If done right this has the benefit that you allocate the last used buffer again. This buffer has a very high probability of beeing in the cache.

If fixed size allocators don't work for you have a look at ring-buffers. They fit the use-cases of streaming audio very well.

*2. To lock, or not to lock:*

I'd say, these days using mutex and semaphore locks are fine if you can estimate that you do less than 1000 to 5000 of them per second (on a PC, things are different on something like a Raspberry Pi etc.). If you stay below that range it is unlikely that the overhead shows up in a performance profile.

Translated to your use-case: If you for example work with 48kHz audio and 100 sample chunks you generate roughly 960 lock/unlock operation in a simple two thread consumer/producer pattern. that is well within the range. In case you completely max out the rendering thread the locking will not show up in a profiling. If you on the other hand only use like 5% of the available processing power the locks may show up, but you will not have a performance problem either :-)

Going lock-less is also an option, but so are hybrid solutions that first do some lock-less tries and then fall back to hard locking. You'll get the best of both worlds that way. There is a lot of good stuff to read about this topic on the net.

*In any case:*

You should raise the thread priority of your non GUI threads gently to make sure that if they run into a lock, they get out of it quickly. It is also a good idea to read what Priority Inversion is, and what you can do to avoid it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion

Answer (score 1):

'I suppose I could use a pool of frames that have been pre-allocated but this seems messy' - not really.  Either allocate an array of frames, or new up frames in a loop, and then shove the indices/pointers onto a blocking queue.  Now you have an auto-managed pool of frames.  Pop one off when you need a frame, push it back on when you are done with it.  No continual malloc/free/new/delete, no chance or memory-runaway, simpler debugging, and frame flow-control, (if the pool runs out, threads asking for frames will wait until frames are released back into the pool), all built in.

Using an array may seem easier/safer/faster than a new loop, but newing individual frames does have an advantage - you can easily change the number of frames in the pool at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Um, why are you passing frames of 100 samples between threads?

Assuming that you are working at a nominal sample rate of 44.1kHz, and passing 100 samples at a time between threads, that presumes that your thread switching rate must be at least 100 samples / (44100 samples/s * 2). The 2 represents both the producer and the consumer.  That means you have a time slice of ~1.13 ms for every 100 samples you send.  Nearly all operating systems run at time slices greater than 10 ms.  So it is impossible to build an audio engine where you are sharing only 100 samples between threads at 44.1kHz on a modern OS.

The solution is to buffer more samples per time slice, either via a queue or by using larger frames.  Most modern real time audio APIs use 128 samples per channel (on dedicated audio hardware) or 256 samples per channel (on game consoles).

Ultimately, the answer to your question is mostly the answer you would expect... Pass around uniquely owned queues of pointers to buffers, not the buffers themselves; manage ALL audio buffers in a fixed pool allocated at program start; and lock all queues for as little time as necessary.

Interestingly, this is one of the few good situations in audio programming where there is a distinct performance advantage to busting out the assembly code.  You definitely don't want a malloc and free occurring with every queue lock.  Operating-system provided atomic locking functions can ALWAYS be improved upon, if you know your CPU.

One last thing: there's no such thing as a lockfree queue.  All multithread "lockfree" queue implementations rely on a CPU barrier intrinsic or a hard compare-and-swap somewhere to make sure that exclusive access to memory is guaranteed per thread.

Comment: You say "more samples per buffer" but then give examples of fewer samples (128 bytes is maybe 32 stereo samples or so)

Comment: Also, RAII-style mutexes don't necessitate dynamic allocation.

Comment: The A in RAII is "acquisition", not "allocation".  `lock_guard` is the prime example of RAII [without any dynamic memory whatsoever](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp)

Comment: The source code you linked has a private Mutex& m on line 29, which is dynamically allocated and copied inside the lock_guard whenever the lock_guard is instanced.

Comment: What dynamic allocation?  What copy?  That's a reference, which at runtime occupies the same space as a pointer.  It lives inside the `lock_guard`, so it will be allocated on the stack (your `lock_guard` instance is an automatic aka local variable, right?  That's how it is meant to be used)  No dynamic allocation anywhere in sight.

Comment: Stack allocations are allocations, and I could tell you about the many projects I've worked on that require all classes to be allocated from heap, including the ones you normally implement on stack.  Nevertheless, to placate you, I've changed the sentence above.

Comment: Edit is better, but you forgot to remove the "malloc and free occurring with every queue lock" bit.  Or can you actually name a single implementation that does that?  (Also, stack allocations do cost stack space, but not CPU time, because the compiler emits just one instruction to adjust the stack pointer no matter how many local variables you have.  The `lock_guard` is not a separate allocation, it's just part of this one bigger allocation.)

Comment: "Most modern real time audio APIs use 128 samples per channel (on dedicated audio hardware)"

Pro hardware can go as low as 16 or 32 samples buffer. The upcoming Bela environment is able to go down to 2 samples.